# What could be causing getDocs() to not retrieve any data based on a specific field in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

```
const getUserData = async () => {
    await getDocs(collection(db, 'accounts'))
        .then((response) => {
            setUserData(response.docs.map((data) => {
            if (Number(data.data().code) === Number(token)) {
                return { ...data.data(), id: data.id };
            } else {
                return {};
            }
            }));
        });
};
```

[image: screenshot of database]

Here is a screenshot for database reference:

I was expecting that the user's data gets fetched if the token/code matches each other, but it actually is not fetching anything at all.

```
UseEffect(() => {
    getData()
    setToken(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    getUserData()
}, [])
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your example, since we don't know the structure of you data nor the condition and `token`. value. I'd start debugging by logging, to see if you don't accidentally end up in the else with condition mismatch.

Comment: I have added a screenshot for you reference!

Comment: We still can't see the value of `token`, so we don't know how this code will run against the data you show.

Comment: The token is actually stored in the localstorage, which i fetched using useEffect hook and stored it in a state called token.

Comment: In that case you'll want to set a breakpoint on `if (Number(data.data().code) === Number(token)) {`, run in the debugger until that breakpoint hits, and check the values used in the line.

Comment: Sorry? I am not able to understand, apologies...